# Проблема при преобразовании String в Integer при чтении из файла. Java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Проблема при компиляции java кода представленного ниже.

Суть программы :

1. она должна считывать название файла из консоли;
2. считывать этот файл (файл содержит целочисленные значения столбцом, т.е. каждое новое число с новой строки);
3. записывать в массив `ArrayList`.

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class Class1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       try {
           BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(bufR.readLine());
           ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
           StringBuilder sbd = new StringBuilder();

           while (input.available() > 0) {
               char ch = (char) input.read();
               if (ch == '\n') {
                   ints.add(new Integer(sbd.toString()));
                   sbd.delete(0, sbd.length());
               } else {
                   sbd.append(ch);
               }
           }
           bufR.close();
           input.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
     }
   }
   ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в строке:

```
ints.add(new Integer(sbd.toString()));
```

Но не знаю почему. 
Пробовал парсингом, тоже не получается.
Быть может проблема в другом, а это лишь следствие?
Буду рад любой подсказке!

Comment: Приведите содержимое файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле, в конце каждой строки идут спец.символы.
Обычно это: перевод строки и перевод каретки (\r\n). Это можно увидеть в отладке.
В итоге вы не строку "123" пытаетесь в Integer приобразовать, а строку "**123\r**".

Самое простое решение - это обрезать начальные и конечные пробелы и подобные спец.символы через метод **`trim()`**:

```
ints.add(new Integer(sbd.toString().trim()));
```

Comment: Вот оказывается из-за чего! Я думал что перевод каретки уже подразумевает перевод строки) Теперь буду знать. Спасибо!

Comment: Все верно, перевод каретки и перевод строки это отдельные независимые символы.

Answer (score 0):

Надо посмотреть исходный файл, возможно там Window окончания строки.

Тогда нужно делать проверку так:

```
if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r') {
```